# primefaces remotecommand partial process

Tags: primefaces, spring-webflow-2

I am working on webflow 2.3.1, primefaces 3.4.2 project.
As you see, i tried to update selectOneMenu according to parent city as shown at example from primefaces showcase. However i used  p:remoteCommand to call webflow action. 
At remoteCommand , if i set process="@this, subSelectOneMenu", action did not call . But if i did not set "process",it called action but it also give error for captcha which is empty.

How can i use remoteCommand to call action partially?

```
        <h:form id="signUpUserInfo">
        <p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2">


            <p:selectOneMenu  id="citySelectOneMenu" value="#{userBean.address.cityId}" label="#{label.address_city}" onchange="selectionChanged()">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{flowScope.cityList}" /> 
            </p:selectOneMenu >

            <p:selectOneMenu id="subSelectOneMenu"
                value="#{userBean.address.subId}" label="#{label.address_sub}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{flowScope.subList}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>


             <p:captcha id="captcha" label="Captcha" language="en" theme="white" required="true" secure="true"  /> 


            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="save" value="#{label.save_button}" ajax="false"
                    action="signUpStandartMember" update="signUpUserInfo" />
            </f:facet>

        </p:panelGrid>

            <p:remoteCommand id="selectionChanged" name="selectionChanged" action="cityChangedAction" update="subSelectOneMenu" process="@this, subSelectOneMenu" />                    



    </h:form>
```